# Router default page login

Tags: login, ip, router, modem

i am having a problem logging in to my router's default login page.
From ipconfig in command prompt the default gateway is 192. 168. 1. 1.
Now when i try to access that via my browser http:// 192. 168. 1. 1 it says "Google Chrome/Mozilla/Internet Explorer could not display the webpage or google cannot connect to 192 . 168 .1 .1
Some times ago i was able to login and i didn't have any problem.
I have tried resetting the router and rebooting it but still it doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you ping this address?

Comment: When u try ping 192. 168. 1. 1 it says:    
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:  
Request Timed out  
Request Timed out :(

Comment: What IP address are you getting?  Is it static or dynamic?

Comment: I have a dynamic ip

Comment: Only points to a few things then - the IP address of your router is incorrect or the router is basically in a sort of "access point" mode.  I'm sure there are other config settings which could cause this depending on the type of router, but doing a hard reset should resolve it (in theory).  Without being able to ping it, you won't reach it.  Also, try doing ipconfig /flushdns a few times, then check the gateway address.  Just a couple of thoughts

Comment: as i said i have already tried resetting and rebooting the modem and it still hasnt worked

Comment: What model is the router?

Comment: Also make sure you are not inadvertently connecting to another network .

Answer (score 0):

The router might require a secure connection.  Try https:// 192.168.1.1 ?